# disable OnClientClick when LinkButton is disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my gridview, I have included a column containing a `LinkButton` that allows you to delete the record on the same row where the `LinkButton` is :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeleteTxn" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TxnID") %>' OnClick="deleteTxn" 
          OnClientClick="return confirm('!!--WARNING--!! You are about to delete the transaction. Performing this action will permanently remove the transaction and all its details from the database. Proceed?');"></asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This `LinkButton` includes showing a pop-up window asking if the user really wants to delete the record. Now, for my `RowDataBound` event, I set it so that whenever the Status of the Record is "Approved", the Delete LinkButton is disabled:

```
string recStatus = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"StatusDesc"));
if (recStatus == "Approved")
{
    hlTxnEdit.Enabled = false;
    lnkTxnDelete.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    hlTxnEdit.Enabled = true;
    lnkTxnDelete.Enabled = true;
    //lnkTxnDelete.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return confirm('!!--WARNING--!! You are about to delete the transaction. Performing this action will permanently remove the transaction and all its details from the database. Proceed?')");
}
```

the problem is, when the user clicks on the disabled LinkButton, the confirmation pop-up still displays, when it should not, because the LinkButton is disabled. Makes a bit of sense, because the Attribute where the pop-up window is set is on the `OnClientClick` attribute. How do I make the pop-up window not show up? I tried adding the `OnClientClick` attribute in the code behind, but it doesn't work. The LinkButton proceeds straight on deleting the record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (recStatus == "Approved")
 {
    hlTxnEdit.Enabled = false;
    lnkTxnDelete.onClientClick = null;//

 }
 else
  {

    hlTxnEdit.Enabled = true;
    lnkTxnDelete.Enabled = true;
    //lnkTxnDelete.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return confirm('!!--WARNING--!! You are about to delete the transaction. Performing this action will permanently remove the transaction and all its details from the database. Proceed?')");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make change in your `aspx` as below...

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeleteTxn" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TxnID") %>' OnClick="deleteTxn"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Add your confirmation pop-up from the code behind like this.

```
string recStatus = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"StatusDesc"));
if (recStatus == "Approved")
{
    hlTxnEdit.Enabled = false;
    lnkTxnDelete.Enabled = false;
    lnkTxnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
}
else
{
    hlTxnEdit.Enabled = true;
    lnkTxnDelete.Enabled = true;
    lnkTxnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('!!--WARNING--!! You are about to delete the transaction. Performing this action will permanently remove the transaction and all its details from the database. Proceed?')");
}
```

Comment: I can't use this because I am already using the `onclick` attribute. My `onclick` attribute calls a function which does the deleting of the record.

Comment: @JamesP, this would be client side click. Just give it a try, it should work without disturbing your server side click event.

Comment: well I tried it, the end result is that, when the status of the record is NOT Approved, the delete LinkButton does nothing. like, really nothing.

Comment: Yes, @JamesP! I fixed the issue by removing the `OnClientClick` from the `aspx` and added the `return false;` part in the `RowDataBound` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue in these steps.

1. Remove the OnClientClick from Declaration html.
2. On GridView OnDataRowBound event handler in the code behind add this OnClientClick

   ```
   lnkTxnDelete.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return confirm('!!--WARNING--!! You are about to delete the transaction. Performing this action will permanently remove the transaction and all its details from the database. Proceed?')");
   ```
3. Make sure you are adding this code only when recStatus <> "Approved".

Comment: please see the sample code above. i HAVE TRIED adding the `OnClientClick` attribute in the code behind, but it doesn't work. I commented it out because it doesn't work. And also, what you're suggesting in Step 3 is the other way around on what is supposed to be done. It's not supposed to be added when recStatus is Approved, because in my system, if a record has a status of "Approved" , you CANNOT DELETE or edit the record.

Comment: Ok I got it in the wrong way. You have to add it in the "else" part. If you are still having the problem, contact me I can fix this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than defining the OnClientClick attribute in template field.
Add the OnClientClick attribute on your RowDataBound event when status is Approved.

```
lnkButton.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick","Javascript");
```